# Retrieving/updating SVG's implicit Viewport value with D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Is there a way to retrieve/update the value  of a svg's viewport with D3.js, although the viewport has not been explicitly defined?

Comment: Like getBoundingClientRect?

Comment: I was thinking to the Viewport property of the SVGSVGElement interface ( https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement ), but retrieved throught a D3.js method